# Angular jquery data table issue / ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have one issue related to query data tables with ngFor directive,
if I use jquery data tables with static data, it works fine, but while using data table with *ngFor directive getting data from http / api service, once I render the page in the first time, I see a perfect result, if I routes to another page and come back I see no data found message and All Table Data at the same time and data table functions like Paging, Filter, search are not working, I should refresh the page again to fix this !!

please assist how to resolve that issue ?!!

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TestserviceService } from '../services/testservice.service';
declare var $: any;
declare var jQuery: any;


@Component({
  selector: 'Test',
  templateUrl: './test.html'
})
export class Test implements OnInit {
  posts: any[];
  constructor(public mytestservice: TestserviceService) { 

    this.mytestservice.getposts().subscribe(response =>{
      this.posts = response.json();
    });

  }

  ngOnInit() {

    $(function(){
      $('#posts').DataTable({
        responsive: true
      });
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card-body">
        <table class="table table-hover" id="posts" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>SEQ </th>
                    <th>User ID</th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Body</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let post of posts">
                    <td>###</td>
                    <td>{{post.userId}}</td>
                    <td>{{post.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{post.title}}</td>
                    <td>{{post.body}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this piece of code -

```
constructor(public mytestservice: TestserviceService) { 

    this.mytestservice.getposts().subscribe(response =>{
      this.posts = response.json();
      $('#posts').DataTable({
        responsive: true
      });
    });

  }

  ngOnInit() { }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.mytestservice.getposts().subscribe(response =>{
      this.posts = response.json();
      $(function(){

        $('#posts').DataTable({
          responsive: true
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: No need to use `$(function(){`